# How does it work in memory with pointers and in general?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Let's say I have a pointer to an int in **C++**.

```
int i = 1;
int* myInt = &i;
```

In `myInt`, I have the information of the memory location to get the actual integer value. I guess that the information in `myInt` has to be stored in memory.

But how does the compiler know where `myInt` is in the memory? I guess it has to keep the address of `myInt` in memory. But where does it keep that last information? `Memoryinception`?

This is more like a general question of how is the memory managed.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler knows where myInt is because it places it in the first place. During compilation a data structure called the [symbol table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) is used to keep track of these locations. Compile code only contains addresses and not variable names (or [lexical names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)).

Comment: Nitpick: Symbol tables of global identifiers are used at runtime for dynamic linking purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Every variable has its own memory address, regardless of what it contains. Therefore, when you are storing a pointer to an integer, you are merely storing an address that points to the variable's data. This address container also has an address. You can experiment by making pointers to pointers and displaying those to your satisfaction:

```
int i = 1;
int* pointer = &i;
cout << "address1:[" << &i << "] address2:[" << &pointer << "]\n";
```

Comment: But when does it stop? In your example, pointer has an address defined by &pointer. That address has to be stored in memory. To know where that address is stored, I need a memory address which also has to be stored. etc.

Comment: Yes, and it will continue like this as long as you create pointers to variables, potentially infinitely. But this chaining doesn't occur until you specifically CREATE a new pointer variable. Otherwise, the address is just the address written on the memory stack like addresses on a street.

Comment: Once you assign that pointer address to a variable for storage, then you are automagically creating a new variable (that happens to store an address), which has its own address and memory size.

Answer (score 0):

Every variable has an address.

Global and static variables are addressed relatively to entire module placed in memory by "loader". Loader reads "module relocation table" , which contains places in code, where adresses should be corrected, and corrects these places. Google: position independent code, too.

Automatic variables (declared in function body) are addressed relatively to activation records. Each time function is called, activation record is pushed on stack, which is "structure" of all automatic variables. Address of activation record is stored in hardware register, which is used to address each variable.

Answer (score 0):

All local variables including pointers are stored on stack. Compiled code uses stack pointer rrlative addressing to access them. So your first variable would be located at 0+sp, your second at size of first variable + sp etc.

Answer (score 0):

The actual address of `i` as well as the actual address of `myInt` is embedded directly into the machine code, into the actual machine commands that accesses `i` and into the actual machine commands that access `myInt`.

These final addresses are not stored in the data storage. Instead they are embedded directly into the flow of machines commands going thorough the CPU. They are called "immediate operands". The CPU receives these address together with the actual machine command, so the CPU does not have to retrieve them from some other location in data memory.

So this is how this seemingly "infinite" recursion stops. This is how it bottoms out.

For global variables, the exact address is know at compile time and is embedded directly into the machine command. For local variables, the address offset in the current stack frame is known at compile time and is embedded directly into the machine command.